# What is the meaning of "Blas zum Antritt an!"?

Tags: meaning

> X: Wirst du mir helfen?
>
> Y: **Blas zum Antritt an!**

I suppose this expression boils down to an enthusiastic "yes!", but I'm at a loss as to how to interpret its meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Right, this means

> I'm ready to help! Now or later, tell me when and I'll be
>   there!

You won't hear *»Blas zum Antritt an!«* on the street, sounds like hunter speech, a command to start a hunt [for wild boars]. Colloquially we would say e. g.

> Sag mir wann! *(Tell me when!)*

or

> Jederzeit! *(Any time!)*

Keywords:

> [anblasen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anblasen) = durch ein Horn, Signal o. Ä. das Zeichen für den Beginn von
>   etwas geben; etwas ankündigen = *give the starting sign for something by using a horn or something similar; to announce something*
>
> [Antritt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Antritt) = der Beginn, das Antreten = *the beginning, the start*

So a more literally translation for *»Blas zum Antritt an!«* could be

> Play the horn to mark the beginning (of my help)!
>   (I will help as soon as I can hear the horn!)

Comment: *Sag einfach Bescheid* wäre auch noch eine gebräuchliche Form, so etwas im Alltag auszudrücken.

Comment: Hi. So basically: "let me know = anblasen" ... "as soon as = zum Antritt" ... "you need my help"?

Comment: @Alone-zee: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best english translation I can think of is

> to sound the rally

IOW, someone blows the horn to make people/soldiers collect for the appeal. Or, alternatively:

> roll call

Answer (score 0):

As has already been explained, *blasen* in this sentence refers to signalling something using a horn. I would like to add that I think that the usage in the example is wrong, though. There is *zu etwas (Dativ) blasen* and also (less frequent, I think) *etwas (Akkusativ) anblasen*. I do **not** think that there is *zu etwas anblasen*. So your correspondent should have answered:

> Blas zum Antritt!